# Show current time on page in real ticks format using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display current time of system on page using Ror.But time will change like on watch that seconds will be continuously changed without refresh page.

currently i am display time using this code

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)").to_s.split(" ").second
```

and it display

```
06:01:43
```

But the problem is it show static time and seconds not increase like on watch.

Comment: You need do that on Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After that I use this code and enjoy....

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $('.main-time-portion').load('/dashboard/give_time');
            }, 1000);
        });
```

where `dashboard` is my controller and `give_time` is action

```
def give_time
    @time = Time.now.utc.to_s.split(" ").second
    render :partial => 'shared/time_portion'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery plugin. There are plenty of them (styled already):

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/07/7-wonderful-analog-and-digital-clocks-using-css-and-javascript/