# Ruby rails - ajax periodical update

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a list of recent items every 5 seconds. The list has to be rendered on every view under that controller. What is a best approach to get it done in rails3? Something like  a ticker. Any got a great solution/example for this?

So I am trying these three javascripts I found on discussion forums. and none of them generating any requests to the server. Any idea why?

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#item_list').load('/item/item_list');
    }, 3000);
  });

$(document).ready(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/item/item_list',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#item_list').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(worker, 500);
    }
})();

function startTimer()
{
   new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('#item_list', '/item/item_list', {
     method: 'get', frequency: 3, decay: 2
   });
}();
$(document).ready(startTimer(););
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answer similar like this please check at this URL.

[Show current time on page in real ticks format using Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361052/show-current-time-on-page-in-real-ticks-format-using-rails/9411835#9411835)